# Smb version 2 upgrade issues

Tags: java, smb

Before the smb version upgrade the code was working fine after it was upgraded to smb 2 , the code throws exception . I know that we can change in Windows to accept smb 1.0 , but I don't want to do that . I want my code to allow smb 2.0 . So Does JCIFS 1.3.15 support SMB verion 2?If it doesn't support what is the best alternate for that.

Comment: Can you show us the exception and the code that throws it?

Comment: I don't have knowledge on smb specifically, but usually in questions like these, the pertinent code and the stacktrace are posted with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jCIFS supports NT LAN Manager 0.12 (NT LM 0.12).
>
> NT LM 0.12 is now called "SMB1", though the accuracy of that
>   designation could be debated.  NT LM 0.12 was introduced with Windows
>   NT 3.51 and also used in Windows 95.  All versions of Windows since
>   that time have supported (and do support) NT LM 0.12.
>
> Windows/XP and Windows 2003 are the last versions of Windows still
>   under support that only support SMB1.  With Vista, Microsoft
>   introduced SMB2. Note that SMB2 is a completely different protocol. 
>   Also note that SMB3.0 is actually SMB2.2 and not a new protocol.
>
> With Windows 2012r2 Microsoft introduced the ability to optionally
>   disable SMB1.  Other than that caveat, all supported versions of
>   Windows still support NT LM 0.12 (SMB1).

[Source](https://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2013-December/010123.html)

To sum up JCIFS supports only SMB v1.

To work with SMB v2 or v3 you can try [smbj](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj)