# Does spring-integration-smb support SMB2 and SMB3?

Tags: spring-integration, smb

I'm wondering what version(s) of the SMB protocol that spring-integration-smb extension is currently supporting. I understand that Microsoft will be deprecating SMB1 soon (or already) and that only SMB2 and/or SMB3 will be supported in Windows Server. Does spring-integration-smb support SMB2/SMB3 protocol today?

I've been reviewing the spring-integration-smb and jcifs code base but I haven't been able to find this answer yet.

Comment: That extension project hasn't had much activity lately; I doubt it. I did a quick google and found [this](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng) which claims to be "A cleaned-up and improved version of the jCIFS library". I don't know if it's a drop-in replacement or if there are API changes. It purports to support SMB2 and "some" SMB3. The extension project is not actively supported by our team, but we're happy to take contributions if it works for you.

Comment: Ok if that's the case then I would like to update the dependant Jcifs library to make it compliant with SMB2. I'm told by our infrastructure team here that MS dropped compliance for SMB1 in 2018.

Comment: Ok I tried to contribute to the project by cloning the repository and creating a branch off of master, however I am having problems pushing my branch back to GitHub so that I can create a PR. I only changed 2 files to update jCIFS to the latest version.

Comment: See the Spring Integration repo contribution guidelines. You need to fork the repo, push your change to a topic branch, then submit a PR to the main.repo.

Comment: Ok I believe I followed the instructions correctly. I've created a PR for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Spring Integration SMB extension is based on the `compile "org.codelibs:jcifs:1.3.18.3" and according some resources in the Internet it support only SMB1: [Smb version 2 upgrade issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015298/smb-version-2-upgrade-issues)

However according the latest news of that project, we are good to tackle their new version with announced SMB2 and SMB3 support: https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs

Feel, free to raise an issue in GitHub project and we also are open to accept a contribution on the matter.

Comment: Ok I will raise that issue in GitHub to upgrade the dependant lib. Thanks!

Comment: There is also another open-source SMB java implementation, written from the ground up: https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj. Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

In case SMB3 is required there is also a commercial option that supports all SMB dialects named jNQ developed by Visuality Systems.